# Poor performance when loading array of SKTexture from Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, sprite-kit

I have a performance bottleneck when playing a SpriteKit animation in my app. The below code causes my app to have a 1-2s delay when loading the SwiftUI view that contains the animated SpriteKit scene. In the below code, I'm populating my [SKTexture] array for animation using image data stored in Core Data.

I believe I might need to anticipate the user opening certain animations and load them ahead of time in the background so they're ready to play.

```swift
for animationFrame in sortedAnimationFrames {
    textures.append(SKTexture(image: UIImage(data: animationFrame.imageData!)!))
```

Comment: The best thing would be to use Instruments to profile this code and see exactly where things are slowing down.

Comment: @TomHarrington I will edit my question to just ask about the slow parts and make it more concise

Comment: @TomHarrington Alright. I narrowed my question to part of my code which is affected performance.

Comment: It would be good to break that line down into parts and profile again. You have three very different things going on in one line-- accessing `imageData`, creating a `UIImage`, and then creating an `SKTexture`. They're all happening some unknown number of times (how big is `sortedAnimationFrames`?) Which one is the problem is hard to say.

Comment: @TomHarrington You're right. I think this can't be done in a reasonable amount of time when loaded. I think I need to anticipate and preload the texture array.